# Filter spark/scala dataframe if column is present in set

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 1.4.0, this is what I have so far:

```
data.filter($"myColumn".in(lit("A"), lit("B"), lit("C"), ...))
```

The function [lit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#lit(java.lang.Object)) converts a literal to a column.

Ideally I would put my A, B, C in a Set and check like this:

```
val validValues = Set("A", "B", "C", ...)
data.filter($"myColumn".in(validValues))
```

What's the correct syntax? Are there any alternative concise solutions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spark 1.4 or older:

```
val validValues = Set("A", "B", "C").map(lit(_))
data.filter($"myColumn".in(validValues.toSeq: _*))
```

Spark 1.5 or newer:

```
val validValues = Set("A", "B", "C")
data.filter($"myColumn".isin(validValues.toSeq: _*))
```

Comment: error: type mismatch; found   : Seq[String] required: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]

Comment: also, could you please explain to me that ": _*" (i'm new here...)

Comment: I have updated my answer, because it worked only in newer versions of Spark. Since `in` method accepts `Column*` as its input, we have to use `": _*"` syntax to convert a regular collection (`Seq[Column]` in this case) into a varargs version of that collection (`Column*`)

Comment: why is a sequence better than a hashset? Default implementation of Seq is List which has to check each element. Surely a hashset uses constant time access instead, no?

Answer (score 6):

[This PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/21416) has been merged into Spark 2.4. You can now do

```
val profileDF = Seq(
  Some(1), Some(2), Some(3), Some(4),
  Some(5), Some(6), Some(7), None
).toDF("profileID")

val validUsers: Set[Any] = Set(6, 7.toShort, 8L, "3")

val result = profileDF.withColumn("isValid", $"profileID".isInCollection(validUsers))

result.show(10)
"""
+---------+-------+
|profileID|isValid|
+---------+-------+
|        1|  false|
|        2|  false|
|        3|   true|
|        4|  false|
|        5|  false|
|        6|   true|
|        7|   true|
|     null|   null|
+---------+-------+
 """.stripMargin
```

Comment: I think it's now called `isInCollection`